# Strange response with dynamic texture and MousePosition

Tags: graphics, memory, textures, dynamic

I built a cubic, then use `MousePosition` together with `GUIScreenShot` to take a floating region with fixed size (200*200) on the screen, and use it as dynamic texture on the cubic. My code is

```
Needs["GUIKit`"];
$HistoryLength = 1;

DynamicModule[{mpp},
 Dynamic@{
  Refresh[
   ClearSystemCache[];
   g = GUIScreenShot[With[{mp = MousePosition[]}, mpp = {mp - 100, mp + 100}]];
   Graphics3D[{Texture[g], Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Table[vtc, {6}]]}, Lighting -> "Neutral"],
   UpdateInterval -> .5],
  mpp, g},
 Initialization :> (
  vtc = {{0, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {1, 0}};
  coords = {{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1}}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}, {{1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}, {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}};)]
```

You can see the result by executing the code then moving your mouse around. Like this,
[image]

But there are two strange problems,

1) the size of the floating area taken should be always 200*200, however it will actually change.

2) the memory usage will constantly grow as we move our mouse, but I have already used `$HistoryLength=1` and `ClearSystemCache[]`.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look very carefully at the documentation. This had me puzzled for a while too:

> When the argument consists of screen coordinates of the form `{{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax}}`, a rectangle from the current screen is captured.

The key part is `{min,max}` like `PlotRange`. Your code produces `{{min,min},{max,max}}`.

I think the memory usage problem is a memory leak in the front end Java code. I don't think there's anything you can do about it except report it to WRI. If you really want to investigate, VisualVM might be helpful, though I have never tried it with Mathematica.

Comment: Yes I was too careless, should have written `mpp = {mp[[1]] + {-100, 100}, mp[[2]] + {-100, 100}}` instead. I will wait for some more time, if the memory problem cannot be solved, I will report it. Thanks!